# What is the time complexity of the following complex function with nested for loops

Tags: python, algorithm, time, time-complexity, big-o

I recently had an exam and the following code was given for me to trace:

```
def create(t, m):
    n = len(t)
    while n > 1:
        s = ()
        for i in range(0, n, m):
            minX = t[i]
            for j in range(i+1, min(i+m, n)):
                if t[j] < minX:
                    minX = t[j]
            s = s + (minX,)
        n = len(s)
        t = s
        print(t)
    return t
```

This is a sample usage of the function: `print(create((11,9,10,6,7,8,5,4,3,2,1), 3))`

The following was the question:

With the above tracing of the print statement, we want to understand the time and
space complexity of the codes in terms of the length n of the input tuple t. Note that the input m is always a positive integer between 2 and 9, and n is much larger than m.

What is the time complexity of the given code above? I think that it is O(n^2 log n) but the answer was just n^2.

Is my answer correct? I have stated my reasons below

---

TLDR:
My reasons are as follows:

I feel that log n is still needed due to the while loop. Even through m is a constant (0 < m < 9), The number of time this while loop runs is divided by 2 each time as n decreases by half each time.

In this case, instead of doing n *=0.5, the length of s is shrinking by almost half each time. In the print statements, s shrank from 11 to 4 to 2 to 1. With the change in m, but the length of tuple stays constant, the rest would either shrink from 11 to 2 then to 1 for m >=6, 11 to 3 to 1 for 4 <= m < 6 and 11 to 6 to 3 to 2 to 1 for m = 2.

As for the rest of the explanations for n^2, the first for loop (i) goes from 0 to n in steps of m (without any breaks in it). The worst case for this loop would be when n is equal to the initial value of n which is the length of the input tuple (n). With a jump of m included, the final n would be n/m (e.g. m = 2, the number of times would be n/2 but this would end up being O(n)). With this loop being in the initial while loop, it would become n * log n.

The nested for loop would then run at each iteration of the outer for loop. The worst case for this is when i is equal to n/2 which would then case the loop to run for n/2 + 1 time which would be O(n). Hence, the final answer should be O(n * n * logn)

---

EDIT:
This is their answer which i disagree with:
Ans: O(n^2), as m is a constant.
The two for-loops (i and j) take time linear to the length of t, which is n + n/m + n/m^2+. This is less than 2n. So, the time taken is dominated by the statement s = s + (minX,).
The lengths of s in one looping of i are of 1, then 2, then 3, till n/m. We can see that this is O((n/m)^2). Then, in the next looping of i, the lengths of s are of 1, then 2, then 3 till n/(m^2). So, this is O((n/m^2)^2. Then, in the next looping of i, the lengths of s are of 1, then 2, then 3 till n/(m^3). So, this is O((n/m^3)^2.

So, the total is: (n/m)^2 + (n/m2)^2 + (n/m3)^2...) < 2(n/m)^2 which is still O(n^2) as m is some constant below 10, and the sum 1 + 1/m^ + 1/m^4 + ... is less than 2.

Comment: Isn't `range(i+1, min(i+m, n))` bounded by `m`, making it O(1)?

Comment: but the max it would go is i + m.. So this range would run from m > m + i > i + 2m and then stop. so would that not take n/2 + 1?

Comment: i+1, i+2, i+3, ..., i+m would be m items.

Comment: I think the designers of this challenge may have overlooked that `s + (minX,)` is not a constant time operation.

Comment: so what does that mean?

Comment: is `s = s + (minX,)` a typo or Python syntax I don't know?

Comment: its a python syntax to concat tuples together

Comment: Thanks for the addition to your question. It shows they did intend it exactly like that. They are correct in their analysis.

Comment: why is it not n^2 log n and just n^2?

Comment: The logarithm has no significance here, as it is just a count of terms that each become exponentially small. Although this sum has a logarithmic number of terms, the significance of the smaller terms rapidly decreases so that the smaller terms are not significant. Posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `n` (which is `len(t)`) will divide by `m` (rounded upwards) in every iteration of the `while` loop.

The two inner loops together will visit every value in `t` exactly once, i.e. `n` visits (in one iteration of the outer loop).

It's a little bit hidden, but `s = s + (minX,)` is the bottleneck, as it *copies* the previous tuple `s` to create a new one. So in terms of the *new* value of `n` (i.e. of `len(s)`), this represents 1+2+...+ work, which is (+1)/2, which is O(²). As this is the *future* , in the first iteration this is O((/)²)

As every iteration of the outer loop `n` is divided by `m`, in total -- expressed by the initial value of  -- we have

O((/)² + (/²)² + (/³)² + ... )

= O(²/² + ²/²˙² + ²/²˙³ + ... )

= O(²/²[1 + 1/² + (1/²)² + (1/³)² + ...])

The inner series is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), with the common ratio  = 1/². As  < 1, the closed form of this inner sum (if it would be infinite) is 1 / (1 − ), i.e. ² / (² − 1). This value is the greatest when we minimise , and  is given as at least 2, so the inner sum cannot exceed the value 4/3.

And so this is O(²/²) = O(²).